# Does white background increase battery consumption of a smartphone?

Tags: technology, mobile-phones

[Here is a page](http://www.2simtv.com/ru/article/16-5-sovetov-dlja-prodlenija-jizni-akkumuljatora-na-ustroystvah-pod-upravleniem-os-android) with tips on how to decrease power consumption of a smartphone (in Russian). One of the tips is to use black background for Google search.

I wonder whether it actually decreases battery consumption given that the screen uses liquid crystals and the highlighting diods work the same way even if all the screen is black.

Comment: It is possible that the point is to reduce CPU usage for rendering

Comment: Some amoled displays used by samsung (at least) use less power to display darker patches. *This is advertised as a feature* in some LED televisions and the bare panels.